# Restart apache forcing it

Tags: apache, centos, restart

I have a Centos server running Apache and sometimes the server is working fine but I need to restart it due to changes in Apache configuration files. I usually execute:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

But sometimes this command hangs for 4 or 5 minutes! It takes very long to stop apache. I know the problem is stopping and not starting cause if I execute systemctl stop httpd.service it also takes 4 or 5 minutes.

Is there anyway to force apache to restart without waiting so long?

Comment: This could be waiting for Apache to become inactive rather than crashing out all currect activity, _just a guess_

Comment: I discovered that if some user set_timeout_limit to 0 (or a very large number) apache takes a lot time to restart... Have no idea why, it should kill all process and restart instead of waiting..

Answer (score 1):

I found that reload option is better than restart httpd service.
systemctl restart httpd

Comment: sometimes I change lots of things on my server and I really need to restart so all changes are updated and that creates my problem.

Comment: I found apache official documentation you can give it a try it should resolve your problem. [link] (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html)